# How to specify "date precision" when querying VSTS through a hyperlink

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, wiql

I am building an email report about VSTS work items where I have some links that should open VSTS queries. The WIQL query is passed as part of the hyperlink URL, see the following link:

[Define a query as a hyperlink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/define-query-hyperlink?view=azure-devops)

I pass the DateTime as date and time ([System.CreatedDate] >= '2019-02-18T08:00:00.0000000Z') not only date. The page that opens has the following error

```
You cannot supply a time with the date when running a query using date precision. The error is caused by «[System.CreatedDate] >= '2019-02-18T08:00:00.0000000Z'».
```

I tried to add `?timePrecision=true` at the end of the URL but it doesn't help.

Any idea how can I use WIQL in hyperlink and pass date & time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query as a hyperlink doesn't support `timePrecision` yet. You need to use rest api [Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to use time precision, for example:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql?timePrecision=true&api-version=5.0

{
"query": "SELECT [System.ID], [System.Title], [System.State] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.TeamProject]='xxxx' AND [System.CreatedDate]>='2019-01-25 11:00 AM'"
}
```

Meanwhile, you could submit a suggestion at the website below to suggest supporting `timePrecision` when define a Query as a hyperlink:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21

Comment: I cannot use the REST APIs since this is a link on a web page. I ended up changing the queries to not use hours but whole days

Comment: The trick of using `?timePrecision=true` was all I needed to overcome the issue on my side,  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Pointed out by [Abdul Rahman Kayali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236384/abdul-rahman-kayali) in the comments, when using the [WIQL API Resource,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) it is possible to supply the `timePrecision=true` optional parameter which enables the time precision.

For example:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/wiql?timePrecision=true&api-version=7.0
```